# 1and1 SPF record not found

Tags: dns, 1and1

I am seeing the spf txt file in my dns settings but when running an mx toolbox test it is not finding the record.

Does anyone have a fix?

Thanks

Comment: MxToolbox is not real time. How long have you waited after adding the SPF TXT? Any DNS changes can take anywhere from 10min to 48 hours depending on many factors.

Comment: As well, if you have been waiting long enough that the record should be there, can you provide an anonymized example JIC?

Comment: I did this a couple hours ago. Let me check again and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Actually the spf records are created automatically in Plesk so it has been there for a long time. I can see the records in the dns template but they are not showing as there in mx.

Comment: I do not know what anonymized example JIC is.

Comment: This is not about websites, but rather about email.   For server administration questions, you would do better to ask at http://serverfault.com/